# nodejs websockets subscribe to multiple channels

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io

The end goal is for my nodejs program to subscribe to multiple channels supplying real-time financial information and processing the streaming data.

In python it is possible to subscribe to multiple channels using the functools/partial and websocket. This allows one python program to subscribe to multiple channels. In my case I am trying to do the same with nodejs/javascript.

[Python websockets, subscribe to multiple channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645865/python-websockets-subscribe-to-multiple-channels)

Is it possible to do something similar in nodejs with a combination of wesocket and some other package?

What I have below works but it outputs the streams from three different channels in one output which is difficult to manage.

```js
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

var sys = require('util');

const WebSocket = require('ws')
const wss = new WebSocket('wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws/')

wss.onopen = () => {
  console.log('Subscribing: BTCUSD');
  wss.send(JSON.stringify(
    {
      "event":"subscribe",
      "channel":"book",
      "pair":"BTCUSD",
      "prec":"P0",
      "freq":"F1"
    }
  ));
  console.log('Subscribing: LTCUSD');
  wss.send(JSON.stringify(
    {
      "event":"subscribe",
      "channel":"book",
      "pair":"LTCUSD",
      "prec":"P0",
      "freq":"F1"
    }
  ));
  console.log('Subscribing: LTCBTC');
  wss.send(JSON.stringify(
    {
      "event":"subscribe",
      "channel":"book",
      "pair":"LTCBTC",
      "prec":"P0",
            "freq":"F1"
    }
  ));
  console.log('Subscribing: ETHUSD');
  wss.send(JSON.stringify(
    {
      "event":"subscribe",
      "channel":"book",
      "pair":"ETHUSD",
      "prec":"P0",
            "freq":"F1"
    }
  ));
}

wss.onmessage = (msg) => {
  var response = JSON.parse(msg.data);
  var head = response["event"];
  var head_body = response[1];
  
  if ( head == "subscribed" ) {
    console.log("channelID = ", response["chanId"], " currency = ", response["pair"]);
  } else {
    console.log(msg.data);
  }
}
```

Appreciate the guidance on this. Am also looking at socket.io. Maybe that can do it?

Comment: I think you might have some luck with socket.io and its built-in functionality for namespaces: https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: yes; think so. will try now.

Comment: I decided to try to see what would happen if I opened a websocket for each channel I wanted to connect to (in total 20). This seems to work but I do not think it is terribly efficient. I will try to use socket.io and am also going to look at autobahn.js which is something else that came up during my research. The code I have implemented so far can be found at https://github.com/gmanroney/cryptoboard . I will add more updates as I progress.

Comment: @GerM What was the solution you came up with for this finally? I am in the similar situation to you and looking for a way to subscribe to multiple channels.