# How to handle multiple sources for WebSocket events?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, apollo

I am in the process of creating a Node/React app who's data model will be hydrated by multiple data sources, all with similar data.  Once the data is received by each source, it is funneled into a common object structure for the `state`.

After the initial static data load, I will want to subscribe to a price update event from those different sources, update the respective values in the data model, perform some calculations and display them.

This question has to do specifically with how to implement these various WebSocket subscriptions.  As I am querying DEX and DeFi exchanges, I have been looking at ethers.js, Web3.  However, I am now learning about Axios and Apollo.  I have seen and done singular implementations and have read some suggestions to use Socket.IO.

I am not trying to handle [WSS subscriptions to multiple channels from a single source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985375/nodejs-websockets-subscribe-to-multiple-channels), but multiple sources.

How do can I manage WSS event subscriptions from multiple sources?