# Creating a Windows event listener with win32evtlog for multiple channels simultaneously

Tags: python, winapi, events, pywin32

I am currently developing some code in python that should behave as a Windows event log listener. At the moment I am using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73050212/create-a-windows-event-listener-with-win32evtlog) question to do it with win32evtlog.EvtSubscribe and it works fine but I have come across two problems.

**1 - Subscribe to multiple channels at the same time:**

I need to listen to multiple channels at the same time, but EvtSubscribe only gets the events from a specific one. Is there a way to subscribe to multiple channels at the same time? I tried doing it with multiprocessing but for some reason the function finishes instead of waiting for user input, like it does when I just do it normally without the multiprocessing. This means the listener will not wait for the events and just closes. The code I tried running is this:

```
paths = {
    "firewall": 'Microsoft-Windows-Windows Firewall With Advanced Security/Firewall'
}

def on_event(action, context, event_handle):
        if action == win32evtlog.EvtSubscribeActionDeliver:
            print("CAUGHT EVENT")

def log_subscribe(type):
    print("in log subscribe")
    channel = paths[type]
    print("path: ", channel)
    handle = win32evtlog.EvtSubscribe(
        channel,
        win32evtlog.EvtSubscribeToFutureEvents,
        None,
        Callback = on_event)
    
    input()
    win32evtlog.CloseEventLog(handle)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    domains = ["firewall"]
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as exec:
        results = [exec.submit(log_subscribe, domain) for domain in domains]            

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            print("HEYY???")
```

Ideally, later I will be able to add new channels to the paths dict and create a listener for each log.

**2 - Cannot access the Security log:**

For some reason the Security log is the only one I cannot access. It always fail with access denied.

```
handle = win32evtlog.EvtSubscribe(pywintypes.error: (5, 'EvtSubscribe', 'Access is denied.')
```

Is there a way to fix this? Ideally I would like to not have to run it as admin to get access.

Is there a better way to tackle this issues? Is there a different approach that I should be considering? Thank you in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - Subscribe to multiple channels at the same time:

I suggest you could refer to the thread: [Python websockets, subscribe to multiple channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645865/python-websockets-subscribe-to-multiple-channels)

> 2 - Cannot access the Security log:

The Security log is designed for use by the system. However, users can read and clear the Security log if they have been granted the SE_SECURITY_NAME privilege (the "manage auditing and security log" user right).  For more information, see [Privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/privileges).